# ReactNavigation - Call parent navigator and change its "cardStyle" and "navigationOption" 's attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have the following code:

```
/**
 * The tab that's is going to stay in the Home Section
 * @type {[type]}
 */
const HomeTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  //Home: Home,
  PostFriends: PostFriends,
  // Another screens
}, {
  tabBarComponent: null,
  mode: 'hide',
  navigationOptions: {
    visible: false // Now I don't want to see this tab, but I'll need it in the future
  }
});

/**
 * The Stack that 
 * @type {[type]}
 */
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  HomeTab: HomeTab,
  // Another screens
}, {
  headerMode: 'float',
  cardStyle: {
    top: -20 // This is the value that I want to change it to make the animation
  }
});
```

In resume, as you can see, I have a hidden TabNavigator, that is inside a StackNavigator, and I want to animate the header of this last as the headers of the most common apps that when the screen scrolls down  then the header goes up until disappear.

Now, I'm inside the PostFriend's Screen that has a ScrollView with a lot of data, therefore, I want to access to the HomeStack, when I scroll on this screen, to change the attributes of "cardStyle" and "navigationOption" to change its values and can make the animation.

This is the code of my Screen:

```
export default class PostFriends extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        const { params } = navigation.state;
       // I tried a lot of black magic to 
       // connect with the HomeStack
    }; 
    /**
     * Constructor of the component
     * @param  {[type]} props [description]
     * @return {[type]}       [description]
     */
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // Some attributes
    }

    render() {
        return (
              <ScrollView>
                  // A lot of data
              </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```